# How to remove trailing zeroes from a binary field in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a issue while inserting the binary value to a binary column in SQL Server 2012.

I am able to insert the value to binary column but when I query the inserted binary value, I could see the unwanted trailing zeroes in the binary value inserted.

For example,
-- creating the table blob with binary field

```
create table blob
(id int,
adata binary(256))

-- inserting binary value 0x730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 into the table


insert into blob values(3,0x730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

-- and then when i select it, 


select * from blob

3   **0x73000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**
```

The queried value is highlighted in bold.

I don't require this column to have these unwanted trailing zeroes.

Could anyone please help me in removing these zeroes from the binary field in the table?

NOTE: We are not supposed to change the table structure.

Thanks in advance.

Raghav Chandra Shetty

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you're not allowed to change the table structure, but if you don't want the trailing zeros, you really should be using a `varbinary` field instead. With just a `binary` column, *those zeros are and will always be part of the data in the table*, and there's no difference between, say, 0x7300 and 0x7300000000.